# Items in recyclerview setting layoutparams wrong

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want in my notice app:
Title exist, text dont exist = title should center vertically
Text exist, title dont exist = text should center vertically

My adapter looks like this:

```
public View view_title, view_text
public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        ...
        view_title = v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        view_text = v.findViewById(R.id.text);   
        title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text); 
        ...
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.title.setText(utilsM.getTitleByPos("tasks", position));
    holder.text.setText(utilsM.getNoticeByPos("tasks", position));

    if ( ( holder.title.getText().length() > 0) && (holder.text.getText().length() == 0) ) {

        holder.view_title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.view_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.view_title.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        holder.view_title.setLayoutParams(params);

        debug("title: " + holder.title.getText());
        debug("text: " + holder.text.getText());

    } else if ( ( holder.text.getText().length() > 0) && (holder.title.getText().length() == 0) ) {

        holder.view_title.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.view_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.view_text.getLayoutParams();
        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        holder.view_text.setLayoutParams(params2);
    } else {
        holder.view_title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.view_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

I found out that i can set the "android:layout_centerVertical="true", in my code with:

```
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.view_title.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        holder.view_title.setLayoutParams(params);
```

All works fine.
But sometimes do notices centering their title or text, although title and text both exist. How?

It looks like this:
[image]

Sorry for my bad english :D
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to remove the `CenterVertical` property in the last `else` bloc for both Texts. And don't forget to align your text to not overlay each other.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.view_title.getLayoutParams();

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.view_text.getLayoutParams();

    if ( ( holder.title.getText().length() > 0) && (holder.text.getText().length() == 0) ) {

            holder.view_title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.view_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

            holder.view_title.setLayoutParams(params);

            debug("title: " + holder.title.getText());
            debug("text: " + holder.text.getText());

        } else if ( ( holder.text.getText().length() > 0) && (holder.title.getText().length() == 0) ) {

            holder.view_title.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.view_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            holder.view_text.setLayoutParams(params2);
        } else {
            // YOU NEED TO RESET YOUR 2 LAYOUT PARAMS HERE
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0);
            params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0);

            // ..... 
            // align your texts here
            // ....

            holder.view_title.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.view_text.setLayoutParams(params2);

            holder.view_title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.view_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

To remove the rule, use:

```
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0);
```

Or (for API level **>=17**)

```
layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

in code ,

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) submitCashbackFailedViewHolder.contentViewRlly.getLayoutParams();

    layoutParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    layoutParams.width = UiUtil.dpToPx(mContext,UiUtil.px2dip(UiUtil.getScreenWidth()) - 23);
```

the problem is that

`layoutParams.height` require px.
 but i had used dp to set it